# How can I declare an anonymous function

Tags: r, magrittr

I would like to know if there are concise way to deal to declare an anonymous function

Say I want to declare `function(x){ return (x=='a') }`, I'd love to be able, I'd like to be able to do `f <- {.=='a'}`

I know that magrittr allows you to do

```
library(magrittr)
{. %>% `==`(.,'a')} # or even . %>% `==`('a')  
{. %>% `==`(.,'a')}('b')
[1] FALSE
```

In the same way if `f = function(x,y,z){return(x+y+z)}` I'd like something like `{f(.$x,3,.$z)}`

When I have `{...}` why do I need `{. %>% }` it looks spurious to me

Comment: Have you tried it? `"a" %>% { . == "a"}`

Comment: I want to declare a function that's not the same thing, have you tried it yourself ? `f = {. == 'a'}`

Comment: Take a look at `pryr`'s `f` function: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pryr/pryr.pdf

Comment: `f(.=="a")("b")` does what you want.

Comment: @statquant done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pryr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pryr/pryr.pdf) is a package that implements a function that does something like this:

`f()` takes an expression and tries to parse it to a function. This doesn't work perfectly 100% of the time, so it is definitely adviced to check the produced function.

To take your example:

```
> pryr::f(.=="a")
function (.) 
. == "a"
```

Which you can call directly as follows:

```
> f(.=="a")("b")
[1] FALSE
> f(.=="a")("a")
[1] TRUE
```

This works with multiple arguments:

```
> f(a+b+c)
function (a, b, c) 
a + b + c
```

and

```
> f(a+b+c)(1,2,3)
[1] 6
```

**When does it not work?**

`f()` doesn't seem to be able to tell variable names and functionnames apart when the functionnames are not called directly. Take the following function for example:

```
function(x){
  apply(x, 1, sum)
}
```

Here `sum` is interpreted as a variable, so parsed to an argument in the anonymous function:

```
> f(apply(x, 1, sum))
function (sum, x) 
apply(x, 1, sum)
```

This can be fixed by explicitly passing the intended arguments for the function in the call:

```
> f(x, apply(x, 1, sum))
function (x) 
apply(x, 1, sum)
```

Comment: thanks Jarko I didn't know this cool function, but you've not been fair, it still works quite well for your last example, you just have to type `f(x,apply(x, 1, sum))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper hmm, didn't realise that worked. I edited my post :)